# Extract the words between a number and alphabets

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string that has both numbers and words where I need to extract the specific word from the string

below is the string

**2014).  Research  in fields like human–computer interactio n1Andrew Burton-Jones was the accepting senior editor for this paper**

I need to extract the word between "1" and "was the accepting senior editor for this paper" where the output should be "**Andrew Burton-Jones**"

Below is the name that I have to extract

2014).  Research  in fields like human–computer interactio n1**Andrew Burton-Jones** was the accepting senior editor for this paper

There could be many formats of such string but the catch is I need to extract the words between a number and sentence i.e; "was the accepting senior editor for this paper"

Below is the code that I tried

```
import re

test_string = "2014).  Research  in fields like human–computer interactio n1Andrew Burton-Jones was the accepting senior editor for this paper"

# Define the regular expression pattern
pattern = r"\d+(.*?)(?= was the accepting senior editor for this paper)"

# Search for the pattern in the input string
match1 = re.search(pattern, test_string)

# If the pattern is found, extract the author name
if match1:
    author_name = match1.group(1)
    print(author_name.strip())
```

but the above code is not giving the desired output. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So your desired match is `"4). Research in fields like human–computer interactio n1Andrew Burton-Jones "`?

Comment: You could match the regular expression `(?<=1).*?(?=was the accepting senior editor for this paper)`, where `(?<=1)` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?=was the accepting senior editor for this paper)` is a *positive lookahead*. `?` following `.*` is an assertion that as few characters as possible are to be matched,...

Comment: ...so if the text were, `"2014).  Research  in fields like human–computer interactio n1Andrew Burton-Jones was the accepting senior editor for this paper and Tom was the accepting senior editor for this paper"` (unlikely as that might be), the match would end with `"Burton-Jones was "`. Without the `?` one would have a *greedy* match (match as many characters as possible) in which the match would end with `"and Tom "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to get group 1, which is exactly what you need.

`\d(\D*?) was the accepting senior editor for this paper`

It is recommended that you use some online tools to debug your regular expressions,like https://regex101.com/

Comment: That link can also be used to test answers, something I suggest you do.